# Error when trying to change the default colour of rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm working to create bounding boxes around the data I need to extract from an image. (I am using Jupyter notebook for python and OpenCV).
For this, I am drawing rectangles of desired coordinates and am using the following line of code:

```
cv2.rectangle(img,(50,82),(440,121), (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

This is for some reason giving only a black rectangle even though (0,255,0) is supposed to give green. What's more, if I use any other colour, for example (255,255,0), the box doesn't appear at all.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the image `img` that you are drawing on binary or grayscale? If so, make it color by merging the same image 3 times so that you have an RGB image with R=G=B. Or convert it Gray2BGR using cvtColor(). That is in Python/OpenCV do either

```
img = cv2.merge([img,img,img])
```

or

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGB)
```